# Some version of MVT(?)

Tags: projective-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

Let $T \in SL(2,C)$ be a normalised Mobius transformation. Then, $$|T(z) - T(w)| =|z-w||T'(z)^{\frac{1}{2}}||T'(w)^{\frac{1}{2}}|$$.

The above is an exercise from Outer Circles by Marden (ex. 1.1).

I was wondering if there is any geometrical significance to the question?

Comment: Presumably $z,w\in\Bbb C^2$. Is $T'$ the adjoint of $T$? If so the $T'(z)\in\Bbb C^2$; what would $T'(z)^{\frac12}$ be???

Comment: Actually, T is a mobius transformation. I forgot to mention that. Sorry

Comment: T' is the derivative

Comment: ??? A linear map (in finite dimension) is its own derivative.

Comment: I updated the question. The derivative will now be $1/(cz+d)^{1/2}$ if $T(z) =(az+b) /(cz+d) $.

Comment: Suddenly the confusion is clear.  If $T(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ then $T$ is **not** a element of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$... i assumed you were talking about a linear transformation, since you said so.

Comment: I think it's ok to use the matrix notation for a mobius transformation if I say T is so. Anyway, do you think there is some geometry going on here. Or, is it purely an algebraic question?

Comment: it's ok, that's just why I was confused about $T'$, etc. What it all means I couldn't say

Comment: Ok. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is extremely common, pretty much universal, for authors to identify Mobius transformations with elements of $SL_2\Bbb C$.

Comment: @runway44 My last comment seems to indicate I understand it's extremely common. Saying that that's where my confusion arose does not contradict this.

Comment: One thing that pops out to me is that the difference quotient $\frac{T(z)-T(w)}{z-w}$ should approximate $T'(z)$ and $T'(w)$ when $z\approx w$, and the other side is the geometric mean of $T'(z)$ and $T'(w)$. What it means that this is an exact equality for all $z,w$ I don't know.

Comment: @runway44 yes, there are many such interpretations from a purely algebraic point of view but I was wondering could there be a hidden picture here